# Unable to detect selector element in a ionic5 application using appium & c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Xunit;


namespace XUnitTestProject2
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            var driver = InitiliseDriver();
            
            //Login Page
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("TestUser");
            driver.FindElement(MobileBy.Id("password")).SendKeys("newpassword");
            driver.FindElement(MobileBy.Id("91268f5d-d21e-4ef5-9886-c1d19f2799a7")).Click();
        }
        private RemoteWebDriver InitiliseDriver()
        {
            //Set the capabilities
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
            cap.SetCapability("platformVersion", "9.0");
            cap.SetCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\jamesa\\Downloads\\app-debug.apk");
            //cap.SetCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
            return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);          
        }
    }
}
```

---

- My nuget packages are Appium.WebDriver(4.1.1); Microsoft.Net.Test.Sdk(16.0.1); Selenium.Support(3.141.0); Selenium.WebDriver(3.141.0); Xunit(2.4.0); Xunit.runner.visualstudios(2.4.0); MSTest.TestAdapter(2.1.2); MSTest.TestFramework(2.1.2)
- My Desired Capabilities are platformName- Text- Android; platformVersion- Text - 9.0; app - Text - \\\

[This is the session details I am getting I do have selector ID but the server is not picking it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHmIY.png)

Note: - I am able to launch the application successfully but the server is unable to pick the element. - The application is built in an Ionic way (Ionic 5)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your driver context to WEBVIEW, ionic builds apps with webview (not native), also you might want to build your app in debug mode. [Here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/) is more details on testing hybrid applications with appium.

In your case you would need to add something like this, before executing the tests

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW");
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply I got the program working by adding the Thread.Sleep(5000) after var driver = InitialiseDriver();